# Как прилично повторить скорректированный вопрос

Tags: обсуждение, неотвеченные-вопросы

Здравствуйте,

известно, что в приличном обществе не принято дважды спрашивать об одном и том же. Поэтому, может ли кто-нибудь из мэтров подсказать новому члену, как привлечь внимание к [переформулированному вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/600943/181472), который изначально не вызвал интереса (16 просмотров), но ответ на который очень важен для задающего.

Comment: Спасибо :). Буду разбираться с конкурсом, но уже утром.

Comment: Разобрался, осталось заработать недостающих 25 балов рейтинга :)

Comment: Объявил конкурс на вашем вопросе. =)

Comment: Уважаемый Nick, большое Вам спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, обращайтесь если что.

Comment: Да, весьма вероятно, что к вопросу будут ещё какие-то уточняющие вопросы в комментариях. Пожалуйста, отвечайте на них. Если окажется, что информации недостаточно для того чтобы локализовать проблему и дать ответ, то конкурс сам по себе не поможет.

Comment: Да, спасибо, я готов отвечать на любые уточняющие вопросы.